# file_sd_configs in Prometheus, cannot unmarshal !!seq into config

Tags: prometheus

My version of Prometheus: 2.46.0, deployed in docker, the required section is forwarded to the container:

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9090:9090
    volumes:
      - /opt/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - /opt/prometheus/scrape_configs:/etc/prometheus/scrape_configs
      - /opt/promdata:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
    restart: unless-stopped
```

With static_configs everything works well. I want to test auto-discovery of services via a file:
my prometheus.yml:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 30s
  evaluation_interval: 10s

scrape_config_files:
  - /etc/prometheus/scrape_configs/*
        
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'cadvisor'
    scrape_interval: 30s
    file_sd_configs:
    - files:
      - '/etc/prometheus/scrape_configs/cadvisor.json'
```

and my /etc/prometheus/scrape_configs/cadvisor.json :

```
[
  {
    "labels": {
      "job": "cadvisor"
    },
    "targets": ["XX.XXX.XXX.120:8080"]
  },
  {
    "labels": {
      "job": "cadvisor"
    },
    "targets": ["XX.XXX.XXX.130:8080"]
  }
]
```

With this configuration, the container does not start; there is an error in the container logs:

```
prometheus  | ts=2023-09-20T11:43:28.451Z caller=main.go:497 level=error msg="Error loading scrape config files from config (--config.file=\"/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\")" file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml err="\"/etc/prometheus/scrape_configs/cadvisor.json\": yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 1: cannot unmarshal !!seq into config.ScrapeConfigs"
```

Tell me how to diagnose the problem?

I tried to use the yml file, but the error is the same

Answer (score 0):

The solution was trivial: you cannot place .json in the /etc/prometheus/scrape_configs/* section, because Prometheus expects to find a configuration file there, and not a file with a list of targets for file_sd detection